# When talking about planned actions vs unplanned actions, What would be the right form...?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, active-voice

"we are focused" vs "We focus".

It would be great if these are explained with multiple Examples..!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to give us some context. Where are these phrases to be used?

Comment: We are focused on giving more room for education rather than sports.

Comment: What is the planned action and what is the unplanned action here?

Comment: One uses an adjective and the other uses a verb. Either could be right, depending on what you're trying to say and how you're trying to say it.